# Using CSS to Moving Columns Based on Screen Width

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to the page that's in development:

http://cybercacher.com/test/about-me/

If you scroll down to the very bottom you will see a list of links - there's 4 columns in the normal view.  When you make the screen smaller, it puts all of them into one column.

I do want it to put them into a single column on an iPhone, for example.  However, based on the screen size it should show them as 4 columns, then 2 columns, then 1 column.

Right now it's only showing as 4 columns or as 1 column, but it won't show like this:  [image]

I've tried playing around with the CSS to see how to do this but can't seem to figure it out.  I'd prefer to do this with just CSS if possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this built on Bootstrap? Code would help.

Comment: Certain parts of Bootstrap are used.  This is a pure HTML scrape of the actual page I'm working on so you can see all the HTML, CSS, etc. that could be effecting this.

Comment: so do you actually want 2 columns like on the image you posted?

Comment: Your screenshot is not visible.

Comment: @redcodealert I want 2 columns whenever there's NOT enough room for 4 columns.  Right now it shows 4 by default and then starts just showing 1 column when the screen is smaller.  But between going from 4 columns to 1 column, it should show 2 until the screen gets too small.

Comment: @isherwood Copy/paste it, modsec is blocking hotlinking on the server.

Comment: so in css from bootsrap, there are different css rules for different screen dimensions, you might want to set the width to 1 column for the smallest devices, then for the medium screen devices 2 columns and for larger 4 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see:

```
col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3
```

Try to use:

```
col-sm-6 col-md-3
```

instead.

Comment: And `col-lg-3` is redundant here. Initially `col-md-3` was, also.

Comment: isherwood is right (as usual ;) ) becase Bootstrap is mobile first.

Comment: It works when changing everything to `-6`, but how do you do that automatically based on the screen size?  Right now it will change it to 1 column automatically, but how do I make it change to 2 columns automatically?

Comment: You need to do some reading and gain a better understanding of how the column classes work with media queries. All you need to do is apply what is given in this answer. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: If you're talking about on phone, do col-xs-6.

Comment: But ish is right just take the time to study the totally free documentation available at getbootstrap.com.